# Node.js MSSQL speed improvements (50 MB = 25 s)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sql-server, database

I have a data table in MSSQL where I want to output three columns using node.js and the mssql plugin. The entire table contains < 300 rows.

**MSSQL Data Types**

- Column 1: int
- Column 2: int
- Column 3: nvarchar(MAX)

The output data size is approx. 50 MB (mainly mumeric arrays with up to 100,000,000 characters) Unfortunately the request takes 24 seconds, which is way too much. Here you see my console output:

```
Connection successful
Startet query after: 0 ms
Got query response after: 23953 ms
{database_pull_timestamp: 1617973785509, data: Array(257)}
Data is displayed after: 24638 ms
```

Can somebody help me to improve my code? I need an JSON output.

```
var sql = require('mssql');
const fs = require("fs");

const SQL_CONFIG = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/../database/database_config.json"));

main();

async function main() {

    await connect_to_database();
    console.log("Connection successful");

    get_data();

}

function connect_to_database() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        sql.connect(SQL_CONFIG, resolve);
    });
}

function get_data() {

    let operation_start = Date.now();

    let template_object = {
        database_pull_timestamp: "",
        data: []
    }

    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var request = new sql.Request();
        console.log("Startet query after: " + (Date.now() - operation_start) + " ms");

        request.query("SELECT id, ident_no, data FROM table_name WHERE active = 1", function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Got query response after: " + (Date.now() - operation_start) + " ms");
                template_object.database_pull_timestamp = Date.now();
                template_object.data = recordset["recordsets"][0]

                resolve(template_object);
            }
        });

    })

    promise.then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("Data is displayed after: " + (Date.now() - operation_start) + " ms");
        process.exit();
    })

}
```

Comment: Did you run a benchmark without the nvarchar(MAX) column?

Comment: Without the last column it takes 40 ms

Comment: As I suspected.  varchar(max) can get heavy.

Comment: Thats alright, but there must be an more efficient way to handle my table. Unfortunately I cant predict the size of the column 3 content, so I need the varchar(max) type to handle the content. On the other hand the MSSQL Server Management Studio handles the query in < 1 s. So I supposed that there has to be a better way with node.js.

Comment: Maybe there is also a better way to store the data in the database? The data structure is an array of numeric arrays. From row to row the count of numeric arrays differs. Example: 

[[int, float, float, int, int], [int, float, float, int, int],...]

Comment: nvarchar has twice the weight of varchar.  varchar would be better if you don't need to support extended character sets.  The VARCHAR(MAX) type is a replacement for TEXT . The basic difference is that a TEXT type will always store the data in a blob whereas the VARCHAR(MAX) type will attempt to store the data directly in the row unless it exceeds the 8k limitation and at that point it stores it in a blob.

Comment: Thank you very much!! With VARCHAR(MAX) I got the result after 12 s. Like you wrote, twice as fast. Is there a even faster way? At the moment my biggest array consits of 49,693,703 characters, but probably I should reserve space for 100,000,000.